# Checking 2 instances of the same object in GameMaker

Tags: game-maker

There are 2 blocks.
If the player stands on a block, some sound should loop and when he gets off it should stop.

Problem is,
The game checks both the objects and when player is on 1 block, obviously he is not on other, so checking this it stops the sound, never letting it play(sound).

```
if place_meeting(x, y-1, obj_player)
{
   if !audio_is_playing(snd_cart)
        {
             audio_play_sound(snd_cart, 10, true);
        }
}
else
    {
        audio_stop_sound(snd_cart)
    }
```

This is the code please help me on this

Comment: Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: And under what event is this code running?

Comment: The easy but ugly fix would be to put that in the player's code instead.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to add a new property to your block object that store whether or not the player is on the block, then tweak the logic so the sound only starts/stops if the player gets on/off.

:Create

```
isPlayerOn = false
```

:Step

```
if place_meeting(x, y-1, obj_player) {
    if !isPlayerOn {
        isPlayerOn = true
        if !audio_is_playing(snd_cart) {
            audio_play_sound(snd_cart, 10, true)
        }
    }
} else {
    if isPlayerOn {
        isPlayerOn = false
        audio_stop_sound(snd_cart)

    }
}
```

(The reason for nesting the `if`s as I've done is to avoid unwanted side effects.)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on obj_player and let the obj_player check the collision and play the sound.
Other turnaround would be global variables, but this is not a good solution.